# Entity-relationship diagram for a shareholding

Tags: entity-relationship, diagram

I have to describe shareholdings, where a subject has a shareholding in an investee company and the shareholding is described by zero or more records.

I don't know what is the correct way to model the "shareholding" part. It sounds like a relationship, but it seems also an entity.

Both diagram 1 and diagram 2 lead to the same logical schema, if I'm not wrong.

Which diagram do you think is the correct one? The first or the second? And why?

And, are the second and the third schema equivalent? (my answer is: yes)

Schema 1:

[image: schema1]

Schema 2:

[image]

Schema 3:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**First**, to address whether or not `shareholding` is an entity or a relationship:
Because `shareholding` describes how a subject and an investee company interact, I'm inclined to think it's a relationship. That being said, you may want to define `shareholding` between the subjects + records and the investee company very explicitly.

**Second**, about which schema is correct:
I think to correctly show that shareholding can be describes by zero or more records, 2 and 3 cannot be correct as those have a `(1,1)` relationship between the `Shareholding` and `Record` entities. Personally I would modify Schema 1 to have `Shareholding` as a relationship shared by `Investee` and `Shareholder`, and then have a `(0,N)` connection between `Shareholding` and `Record` directly (if possible). This would show the actual relationship between the two, rather than a middle-man `Descriptions` relationship, but  may be off on how these things interact in your system, so that's your call on what makes the most sense. :)

I'll also say that I like the `(0,N)` between `Subject` and `Shareholding` in Schema 2.

**Third**, on if Schema 2 and Schema 3 are equivalent:
Yes, these are equivalent, because you kept the `Shareholder` and `Investee` relationships consistent in the two. If you'd changed them to entities in Schema 3 the scenario would have been different, but in Schema 3 you pretty much just made it more explicit what `Shareholding` is. That being said, Schema 2 is much more clear.

I hope this helps! I'm by no means a master of ERDs and happy to discuss this if you want! :)

Comment: You're right, schemas 2 and 3 allow only one record for an instance of <shareholder, investee>. But in your second consideration, I don't understand how you would make the model: you say to have a `shareholding` relationship shared between `investee` and `shareholder`, do you mean like it is in schema 2? I understand that you suggest a schema 2 modified to have a `(0, N)` cardinality between `record` and `shareholding`, but if I'm not wrong that would mean that a `record` could describe more than an instance of `<investee, shareholder>`, which is not correct.

Comment: I think if you change it so a record can only describe a shareholding, and then the investee and shareholder each have a (1,1) with a shareholding, that would work? I'm not sure what that looks like though.

Comment: What you say here seems a description of the first schema... In your answer (second part), you suggested to link shareholder and investee to shareholding with shareholding being a relationship, but relationships can only be linked to entities, not to other relationships... so I ask you: did I understand correctly that shareholding, investee and shareholder should be all relationships?